# Cannot save data using HTML 5

Tags: html, sqlite

```
   <html>
          <head>
            <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/cordova.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" >
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
          function populateDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
            }

            function queryDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
            }
         function querySuccess(tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length;
                alert("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
                for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    alert("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
                }
            }


            function errorCB(err) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
            }

            function successCB() {
                var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
                db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
            }


            function onDeviceReady() {
                var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

            }

            </script>
          </head>

        </html>
```

I run above example code to Save data on sql lite database  using HTML 5.When 
i run above code on tab. .But when u try this get following error.But rows are saved on database sucessfully.

```
10-25 14:40:31.246: E/SQLiteLog(2584): (1) no such table: DeletedCacheResources
```

Answer (score 0):

The onflict is between these two lines:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo",
```

and

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)
```

You probably got them from two different pages.